# error in proxy in rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, proxy

0
votar en contra
favorito
I've tried to run a gem in rubymine and I have the following error:

> ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why: Unable
>   to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name
>   (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Then I configured the proxy like this:

```
set http_proxy=http://user:pass@serv:port
```

and I had the following error:

> ERROR: While executing gem ... (Net::HTTPServerException) 407 "Proxy
>   Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to
>   fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied. )"

Could you know what can it be?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It should be "https://rubygems.org/" instead of "https rubygems.org/" (missing `://`). Make sure that you have a proper value for `source` in Gemfile.

Comment: Your second error says that proxy credentials are invalid or a further steps are needed to use it. However you should be able to download rails gem without proxy unless there is some block from ISP or someone). Anyway, are you able to install gem directly from the console?

Comment: i cannot install the gem from my console because i have the error that is above. I tried to install it bydownloading the gem and then executing the command "gem install --local rails-5.0.0.gem" and i had this error: ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'railties' (= 5.0.0) in any repository